# Save pointer to appropriate location in struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Not exactly sure how to assign the new student records grades to grades inside of the *grades_array.

It will not allow me to access the point of the grades with new_student_record.grades[i'th element].

```
new_student_record.grades[i'th element] = grades_array[i'th element];
```

doesn't compile.

```
typedef struct student_record{

float * grades;

}student;


student input_student_info(int varGrades){

    student new_student_record;

    //varGrades is given from user input...        

    float *grades_array = (float *)calloc(varGrades, sizeof(float));

    //Save this pointer in the appropriate spot in the student record.

    for(int i = 0; i < varGrades; i++){
    scanf("%f",&grades_array[i]);
    new_student_record.grades = grades_array; //stuck here
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is wrong with `new_student_record.grades = grades_array;` (other than you should probably assign it once before or after the loop?)

Comment: You say your code doesn't compile. But it compiles cleanly in my case. The only thing i see wrong is assignment of `new_student_record.grades = grades.array` in for loop.

Comment: if you replace new_student_record.grades = grades_array; with  new_student_record.grades[I] = grades_array[I]; It doesn't compile. I'm trying to point the i'th element of the pointer in the struct to the i'th element to the array of *grade_array

Comment: There is no "i'th elemnt of the pointer in the struct". Where do you set that pointer if not in the way shown in the second code snippet? You can't do `new_student_record.grades[i]` unless `new_student_record.grades` has a valid value first.

Comment: pewpew: but there is only one float* in struct ?

Comment: Wow thanks. LMAO. You guys helped me. Made me realize my problem was in a different area of the program. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write

```
new_student_record.grades[i]
```

you have to change your struct to something like this

```
typedef struct student_record{

float grades[20];

}student;
```

or dynamically allocate space with malloc:

```
new_student_record.grades = malloc(n*sizeof(float));
```

If you use malloc you will have to free to allocated space since your struct is a local variable

```
free(new_student_record.grades)
```

otherwise you will have memory leak

this:

```
new_student_record.grades = grades_array; //stuck here
```

is valid, but place it outside the loop.Now you can write

```
new_student_record.grades[i]
```

and you will get what you placed in grades_array

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to solve your problem in my computer,and my computer is running Centos 6.5.In your code,you said you can't access to the new_student_record[i],i think it is beacause the first time you create the struct and you didn't initialize the new_student_record.grades,so it is point to some useless places.And in your for loop,you assign the grade_array to the   new_student_record.grades after you get the value from the input.I put the "new_student_record.grades = grades_array" after i create the struct.Here is my code.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   typedef struct student_record{
   float* grades;
   }student;

   student input_student_info(int varGrades){
   student new_student_record;
   //varGrade is given from user input
   float* grades_array = (float*)calloc(varGrades,sizeof(float));
   new_student_record.grades = grades_array;
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < varGrades; i++){
   scanf("%f",&grades_array[i]);
   }
   for(i = 0; i < varGrades; i++)
  printf("%f\n",new_student_record.grades[i]);
  }
```